# Problemas con LINK image-background ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: html5, css3, asp.net-mvc

Porque no me aparece la imagen al hacerlo desde la hoja de estilos, yo la necesito en el header por tal razón lo hago desde una clase...

```
.font {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('../Images/index/font.jpeg');
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Si llamo a la imagen desde el cshtml si me aparece, pero necesito que la imagen se adapte a la altura del dispositivo

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/index/font.jpeg")" alt="Inicio" style="width:100%;position:center;">
```

Alguien me puede dar una solución?...

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no has entrado al directorio `Content` si analizas el sitio con las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador verás que tu imágen sale con error 404 prueba esto:

```
.font {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('../Content/Images/index/font.jpeg');
    min-height: 100%;
    }
```

otra cosa fíjate que la etiqueta html a la que le has aplicado la clase `font` sea la correcta, y yo le cambiaría el nombre de clase por otro ya que `font` poedría enredarte un poco. Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: No, amigo, de ninguna manera me ha cargado la imagen, sigue sin aparecer..

Comment: Dime en que dir tienes las imágenes dentro de tu proyecto